# HttpResponseMessage not returning 400 Bad Response

Tags: c#, httpresponsemessage

I have a method within a project that checks the Http response of a URL, called ValidateAcsUrl.
[image: ValidateAcsUrl]

In the method, the Http response of the URL is checked, and returned as a string.

The URLs I am testing have responses of:

- 200 OK
- 400 Bad Request
- 404 Not Found
- 500 Internal Server Error
- And in the catch exception, if the response does not work then an "Unavailable" response is returned

All of the responses work, apart from the 400 Bad Request.

An example of a working URL is shown below, in debug mode.
[image: 200 OK Response]

The 400 Bad Request response URL (using Appending/%, after a working URL) jumps from the HttpResponseMessage line into the catch exception, which returns "Unavailable".

[image: 400 Bad Request Response]

Does HttpResponseMessage not work with a 400 Bad Request, or is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Maybe you can share what is the Exception you are getting? There are multiple reasons possible for HttpClient to throw the exception, error message would provide you some hints

Comment: Very important, you must read this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I'm voting to close this on the basis that it seems to be a typo. You are missing a scheme from the URL (`https://` or `http://`).

Comment: Also read the exceptions. It tells you that you have an invalid URI. They're not there to annoy you. They're there to give you useful information with which to diagnose problems.